# How to Remove the Custom Theme Panel from a Theme?

Tags: customization

How does one remove the custom theme admin panel from a theme that has the options to change colours, layouts, etc?

Thanks.
K

Answer (score 1):

The three easiest options:

1. Limit users' user role to **Author** or below
2. Change the $cap parameter from `'edit_theme_options'` to `'edit_options'` in the `add_theme_page()` call that adds the settings page
3. Remove the settings page entirely, by removing the callback that adds the settings page. e.g. if the Theme uses:

   ```
   function theme_slug_add_settings_page() {
       add_theme_page( $args );
   }
   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_slug_add_settings_page' );
   ```

   Then you would remove that via:

   ```
   remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_slug_add_settings_page' );
   ```